# Is it possible to include an html file inside a php file

Tags: php, jquery, include

I need to include a html file inside a php file, I tried using `include` and `require` in php file, but css styles are not applied and only the content is included. Is there a way to include the full html file with styles and jquery?

Comment: as long as your css and scripts declaration is inside the php file you are `include`-ing, it should be fine :o

Comment: make sure your included HTML matches PHP codes, e.g. don't create 2 HTML heads in 1 page. Review your finalized source codes in browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such thing as a PHP script. There's just files that happen to contain PHP code blocks. You can `include()` anything you want, but unless that included file has a `<?php ... ?>` block in it somewhere, the file's contents will simply be treated as output.

If css isn't being applied, then make sure that that your style sheets are actually being loaded, and that the HTML is being included in the proper place in your page's DOM.

Comment: Agree, make sure to check your <link> tags inside the html, check the paths, myabe the problem lies there.

Comment: there was a problem with path to css files, thanks for the answer, but<!--#include virtual="file.html"  --> are not inclued, even though the path is correct, is there any solution to that?

Comment: @sewdil if your file(s) are not all in the same folder(s), you will need to use `absolute` path. e.g. `<!--#include virtual="/path/to/file.html" -->`. Also, if I may suggest; if you're going to use the `.shtml` equivalent, include another `.shtml` file, that way you will be able to include more later on, should you choose to do so.

Comment: @sewdil To add, if your file is in the same folder, add a `./` in front of your filename. e.g. `<!--#include virtual="./file.html" -->` which could be problemsome. You can also use `<!--#include file="./file.html" -->`, but that directive calls for `ALL` files to reside inside the `SAME` folder.

Answer (score 2):

View the source of the page and see the path of the CSS file it's showing. The path needs to be either absolute or relative to the PHP file's path. Example:

```
File structure:
./index.php
./html/myfile.html
./html/css/style.css

myfile.html includes "css/style.css"
index.php includes html/myfile.html
```

Now, myfile.html may look alright when you open it directly, but the style won't be applied when you include it in your PHP file. Here's why:

If you view the source of index.php (open in browser and view the DOM) you'll see that it's trying to load `css/style.css` but that file doesn't exist. Instead, it should be `html/css/style.css` so you would have to edit your HTML file to reflect that.

Answer (score -3):

```
<script>
        $(function(){
        $("#include_html").load("includeheader.html");
        });        
</script>
............................................................
<body>
      <div id="include_html"></div>
................................
</body>
```